# Xamarin Play Sound From From Embedded Resource

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, resources

I"m very new to Xamarin development. I want to play sound files from the Embedded Resources, to prevent having to copy and paste the same resource in iOS, Android and Windows project folder.

I'm already able to play the resource on Android using the following method:

```
      public void PlaySound()
    {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(context, Resource.Raw.some_sound); 
        mediaPlayer.Start();
        mediaPlayer.Completion += (sender, e) =>
        {
            mediaPlayer.Reset();
        };
    }
```

Now I was hoping that I don't have to reference from the **raw** folder, and just give a path that points to the embedded resource -- Is this at all possible (for all platforms) that play the audio from the embedded resource path?

The point is to prevent having to have the same resource being copied to all projects.

Comment: as of now on vs2017 , adding mp3 to    resources.raw folder fails at runtime  with this ``: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)' on a null object reference``.   some guy  said that look here for  Resources.folder names  .  and as of now there is no RAW folder  in this doc. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources )
and he suggest that we shoud use **assets folder**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible. You can however have your projects link to the files instead of copying them to each of their resource folders.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that makes sense, given how Android needs different images for different screen densities.

Comment: Accepting the answer since there aren't any other answers. :)